# What is the fastest way of finding if object has a value (multidimensional object)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an multi-dimensional object that has a 3 level depth. I am trying to if  the 3rd-level object has a given value. What comes to my mind is for-looping through each level and checking with `(Object.values(obj).indexOf('red') > -1)` but as far as I understand, for looping is a slow way.

For example, in the below object, what is the fastest way to check if any of the most inner values have `red` value or not, returning a boolean?

```
myObj: {
   user1: {
      apples: {
        1: "red",
        2: "green",
        3: "black"
      },
      cherry: {
        2: "green"
        4: "dark"
      }
   },

   user2: {
     orange: {
        1: "orange"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, why not use `myObj.user1.apples` and search on it?

Comment: for-looping is just as slow as using `Object.values`. And no, there's no better way than a linear search, unless you build a lookup structure (that will only become efficient if you need to do many lookups).

Comment: @ankabout It is just a pseudo example. Sorry that it's too dummy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive method that uses [`Oject.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if a value exists in an object:

```js
const obj = {"user1":{"apples":{"1":"red","2":"green","3":"black"},"cherry":{"2":"green","4":"dark"}},"user2":{"orange":{"1":"orange"}}};

const findValue = (o, val) => Object.values(o)
  .some((v) => v && typeof(v) === 'object' ? findValue(v, val) : (v === val));
  
console.log(findValue(obj, 'red'));
console.log(findValue(obj, 'gold'));
```

Comment: Thanks. I always miss the old `null` is an object :)

Comment: Why do you think that this is the "fastest way", what's the advantage over nested for loop that the OP considers "slow"?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am looking at both, but which one is actually better? I quite like this approach solely because it's less lines

Comment: @senty at "both"? What am I, chopped liver? And just because a snippet is shorter, doesn't necessarily make it more efficient by any means.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Chopped liver xD. Which one of those 3 answers are more efficient?

Comment: @senty I might be biased, but the fact that both of these answers use `Object.values()` means that they're _actually_ breadth-first and not depth-first, while mine which uses a `for...in` is _actually_ depth-first since it iterates [lazily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and is therefore going to reach the deepest layer first, _and_ without as many function calls as these, which also creates more overhead.

Comment: Kudos for linking to documentation. up'ed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's still depth-first, it just takes (much) more memory by collecting all values into an array at each step before iterating them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and look for nested objects.

```js
function contains(object, value) {
    return Object.values(object).some(
        v => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? contains(v, value) :
            v === value
    );
}

var myObj = { user1: { apples: { 1: "red", 2: "green", 3: "black" }, cherry: { 2: "green", 4: "dark" } }, user2: { orange: { 1: "orange" } } };

console.log(contains(myObj, 'red'));
console.log(contains(myObj, 42));
```

An other solution could be to use a stack an perform a linear search without a recusion.

This works as [breadth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

```js
function contains(object, value) {
    var stack = Object.values(object),
        v;

    while (stack.length) {
        v = stack.shift();
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            stack.push(...Object.values(v));
            continue;
        }
        if (v === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var myObj = { user1: { apples: { 1: "red", 2: "green", 3: "black" }, cherry: { 2: "green", 4: "dark" } }, user2: { orange: { 1: "orange" } } };

console.log(contains(myObj, 'red'));
console.log(contains(myObj, 42));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do you think that this is the "fastest way", what's the advantage over nested for loop that the OP considers "slow"?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, sorry, imho it's breadth-first search, because the recursive call looks first to children and later to neighbours, even if the neighbour are collected first, but not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive depth-first function to iterate through the keys, and then at the deepest level, just return `true`. One "gotcha" is to make sure that strings don't return single character strings when iterating since that will just recurse infinitely.

```js
function hasKey(object, depth = 0) {
  if (depth === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  for (const key in Object(object)) {
    const value = object[key];
    // prevent nested checks of characters in strings
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || value.length !== 1 || typeof object !== 'string') {
      if (hasKey(value, depth - 1)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

let myObj = {"user1":{"apples":{"1":"red","2":"green","3":"black"},"cherry":{"2":"green","4":"dark"}},"user2":{"orange":{"1":"orange"}}};

// has keys at depth 3
console.log(hasKey(myObj, 3));
// does not have keys at depth 4
console.log(hasKey(myObj, 4));
```

While this answer may be longer in line-count, it truly iterates the keys at each depth rather than buffering all the `Object.values()` into an array at each depth, which technically disqualifies the other answers from being able to claim a "depth-first" approach, since the buffering causes "breadth-first" behavior.